# How do I use Zhonya's Hourglass with AP Kennen?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been playing AP Kennen for awhile now with many people recommending I use Zhonya's Hourglass. I'm not sure how to use item effectively so I was hoping for some advice. The only thing I could guess would be to use it after I use my ultimate in a team fight. Would this be a good idea and/or is there any other ways to use it well?

Answer (score 6):

You're right. The best way to use Zhonya's Hourglass is by using it in a teamfight. Lightning Rush in, try to hit as many targets as you can, then activate Electrical Surge, then Slicing Maelstrom. Here is the description for Kennen's ultimate, along with the description for Zhonya's hourglass, from the League of Legends wikia page.

> Kennen summons a magical storm that deals magic damage to a random enemy champion near Kennen every 0.5/0.4/0.33 seconds. The storm hits several times, increasing with level, and cannot hit the same target more than 3 times. A Mark of the Storm is applied to enemies each time they are hit.
>
> Unique: Places your champion into stasis for 2 seconds, rendering you invulnerable and untargetable but unable to take any actions. 90 second cooldown.

- At level 6, You can get four Marks of the Storm.
- At level 11, You can get five Marks of the Storm.
- At level 16, You can get six Marks of the Storm.

Add this to your two marks of the storm on each opponent with your E-W combo, along with any Marks of the Storm added from your ultimate before using Zhonya's hourglass. You can potentially stun all opponents.

Since Kennen's ult is very powerful due to its utility, enemies will try to focus you down to avoid stuns. That's when you want to Zhonya's. When it's active, you will continue to stun enemies.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, Kennen maximizes his damage by running into the middle of his opponents.  This is abnormal for mages, who generally try to stay away back.  Zhonya's allows Kennen to rush in, deal his damage and ignore some of the damage thrown back at him.

Comment: @Toast Yup, making zhonyas an even better choice due to its armor bonus.

Comment: Could you post a link with an example video? It's very clear when you see it in action.

Answer (score 3):

Because of Kennen's lackluster AP ratios, many summoners will disregard Kennen in teamfights until after the salvo of stuns has been unleashed because he will not be anywhere near as much of a threat as the AD, for example. I've found that waiting to use Zhonya's until I start to take some damage is a better option than clunking down with it immediately, that way you are able to get an extra stun or two off with your combo, as well as disrupt the enemy team even moreso by denying them the chance to focus on your team (because you're in their face stunning all of them), and denying them the chance to focus on you (because you're invincible for two seconds).

Rule of thumb: 
Only use Zhonya's once you start taking serious damage.